# How to override Django model creation without affecting update?

Tags: python, django

I overrided the `save()` method of my `Foo`class so that when I **create** a Foo instance, some logic occurs. It works well.

Nevertheless, I have other methods in other classes that **update** `Foo` instances, and of course, I have to save changes calling the `save()` method. But I want them to directly update without passing into the logic I made for object creation.

Is there an elegant solution to that?

What about overriding `__init__()` method instead of `save()`? (I was told it was a bad practice, but not sure to understand why)

Thank you.

Comment: @perror? Are u sure it is duplicate? It's not the same question.

Comment: No, I did realize it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not override `__init__`, because that is called in all cases when a model is being instantiated, including when you load it from the database.

A good way to do what you want is to check the value of `self.pk` within your save method: if it is None, then this is a new instance being created.

Comment: Yes, that's it!! Just found the same on a blog, simple and clever, thanks.